# Outputting Array Data in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have scoured the internet looking for a working method to achieve what i need to, but had no luck so far.

Basically, I have an AJAX request which runs a database query and echo's everything into a json_encode function doo-dah -> `echo json_encode($row);`

Now, this is then passed back to my Javascript, and this is where i'm stuck. I need to access the JSON array and select various parts for use to alter input field values dynamically. This is the code i have to run the AJAX request and retrieve the JSON array.

```
var vars = new XMLHttpRequest();
    vars.onload = function() {
        var retrieved = new Array(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("testingOutput").innerHTML = retrieved;
};

vars.open("GET", "https://my.url.here", true);
vars.send();
```

Below is what I have tried with no success (Novice to JS..)

```
var forename = retrieved['first_name']; // Didn't work
var forename = retrieved[1]; // Didn't work either
```

I have also tried 'for' loops, which haven't worked either (cannot locate the example i copied off..). I was at first trying to set the retrieved var to just `(this.responseText)` with no luck either. I literally just need a way that i can pull out parts of the array to stick into some jQuery like below:

```
$("#firstname").val = forename;
$("#lastname").val = surname;
```

(where 'forename' and 'surname' are the js variables from the array..)

Any help is appreciated as i am losing my mind!!

**EDIT:** When i was just using `var retrieved = (this.responseText);`, when i used `typeof` it said that the type was a string.. and `var retrieved = new Array(this.responseText)` comes back as an object.. I'm not sure how to access either.

Comment: It looks like you're sending _JSON_, so you'll need to _parse_ that _JSON_ in your _JavaScript_ to make it into a native object `var retrieved = JSON.parse(this.responseText);`

Comment: try `console.dir(retrieved)` to look at the structure of the variable in your browser console, you may find out how the stuff inside it is structured and can access the field then.

Comment: @PaulS. You Sir, are a god of men. Worked a treat. You deserve to be knighted. Thankyou so so much!! I've literally been banging my head against my desk trying to find an answer to this, and it was literally one line! Please submit that as an answer, and i'll accept it once StackOverflow will let me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're sending *JSON*, so you'll need to parse that *JSON* in your *JavaScript* to make it into a native object

```
var retrieved = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

You can read more about [`JSON.parse` **here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

---

As [suggested by kiltek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921087/outputting-array-data-in-js/31921202#comment51754886_31921087) it is also a good idea to use `console.log` or `console.dir` when debugging so you can view the data structure you are working with